# Why is Auth::attempt always returns false in Laravel 5.3?

Tags: php, authentication, laravel-5.3

I'm new in Laravel. I try to use Multiple Auth in Laravel 5.3 and my auth.php file is:

```
<?php

return [

    */

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

    'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'courier' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'couriers',
        ],

        'client' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'clients',
        ]
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'couriers' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Courier::class,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Client::class,
        ],

        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ]
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'couriers' => [
            'provider' => 'couriers',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
        ],
    ],

];
```

Then, when I store Clients or Couriers in the DB, I use `bcrypt` for password (Bring also use the function `Hash::make()` for passwords). For example, my model Courier is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Courier extends Authenticatable
{
  [..]

  public function setPasswordAttribute($pass){
        $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($pass);
    }

  [..]
}
```

And when update a courier, in my controller I have:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id) {

        $fieldsCourier = $request->all();
        $courier = Courier::find($id);

        if( isset($fieldsCourier['password']) )
            $fieldsCourier['password'] = bcrypt($fieldsCourier['password']);

        if( $courier->update($fieldsCourier) )
            $courier = Courier::find($id);

    }
```

I have a method called authenticate but the method attempt always return false (invalid_credentials). Even so send valid credentials.. This is my code:

```
public function authenticate(Request $request) {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        try {
            if ( auth()->guard('courier')->attempt($credentials) ){
                $user = Auth::guard('courier')->user();
            } else {
                return response()->json(['error' => 'invalid_credentials'], 401);
            }
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
            return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500);
        }

        return response()->json(compact('user'));
    }
```

I not know what I'm doing wrong. Anything am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

you have encrypt the password twice, on your model and controller.

just remove one of them

e.g: don't use `bcrypt` on your controller, because you have already use `bcrypt` on your model.