# Laravel Auth::attempt() returns false

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5

I am a home hobbyist and am studying Laravel, currently in version `5.3`. I am using a Mac, neither `homestead` nor `vagrant`.

I'm currently working on a website that uses a login and a register system to create users.

I've used `php artisan migrate` to manipulate my database locally.

[image: Screen Shot 2016-12-27 at 4.18.38 PM.png]

As listed below, it has three fields, namely:

- Email
- Username
- Password

I have a `User` model (users.php):

```
<?php

namespace blog;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable;

class User extends Model implements Authenticatable {
    use \Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;

    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

}
```

And also, a `UserController` class (UserController.php):

```
<?php

namespace blog\Http\Controllers;

use Auth;
use blog\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class UserController extends Controller {

    public function postRegister(Request $request) {
        $username = $request['username'];
        $email = $request['email'];
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

        $user = new User();
        $user->email = $email;
        $user->username = $username;
        $user->password = $password;

        $user->save();

        return redirect()->route('login');        
    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request) {

        $credentials = [
            'username' => $request['username'],
            'password' => $request['password'],
        ];

        if(Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect()->route('dashboard');       
        }

        return 'Failure'; 
    }
}

?>
```

As you can see, I am using `bcrypt()` as my hashing method.

However, this problem is, it will always result to a failure.

[image: Screen Shot 2016-12-27 at 4.41.38 PM.png]

I have checked the following links:

- [Why is Auth::attempt always returns false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40537013/why-is-authattempt-always-returns-false-in-laravel-5-3)
- [Laravel authattempt return false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074273/laravel-authattempt-return-false)

P.S. These links seem very hard to follow as I do not utilize the `Input` class.

Comment: Laravel comes with its own [authentication controller](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication). Why don't you use it instead of writing your own?

Comment: Your route 'login' is with GET method? Can you please attach your routes?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is with the way you're redirecting the user to `login` route after the registration. You're falsely assuming that the `$request` data will be accompanied with the redirect.

Let's assume this scenario: A request gets dispatched to the `postRegister` method with `name`, `email` and `password` fields. The controller creates the user and saves it into the database. Then it redirects the user, who is not yet authenticated, to the `login` route. The `postLogin` method gets triggered, but this time with no request data. As a result, `Auth::attempt($credentials)` fails and you get that nasty `Failure` on screen.

If you add a `dd($credentials)` right after you create the array, you'll see that it has no values:

```php
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    $credentials = [
        'username' => $request['username'],
        'password' => $request['password'],
    ];

    // Dump data
    dd($credentials);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    return 'Failure';
}
```

It will return something like this:

```php
array:2 [
  "username" => null
  "password" => null
]
```

You cannot redirect with custom request data (unless with querystring which is part of the URL), not matter what. It's not how HTTP works. Request data aside, [you can't even redirect with custom headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218304/65732).

Now that you know what's the root of your problem, let's see what are the options to fix it.

#### 1. Redirect with flashed data

In case you want to preserve this structure, you need to flash the request data of `postRegister()` into the session (which is persistent between requests) and then retrieve it in the `postLogin()` method using `Session` facade, `session()` helper or the actual `Illuminate\Session\SessionManager` class.

Here's what I mean:
(*I slightly modified your code; dropped extra variables, made it a lil bit cleaner, etc.*)

```php
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    // Retrieve all request data including username, email & password.
    // I assume that the data IS validated.
    $input = $request->all();

    // Hash the password
    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

    // Create the user
    User::create($input);

    // Redirect
    return redirect()
        // To the route named `login`
        ->route('login')

        // And flash the request data into the session,
        // if you flash the `$input` into the session, you'll
        // get a "Failure" message again. That's because the 
        // password in the $input array is already hashed and 
        // the attempt() method requires user's password, not 
        // the hashed copy of it. 
        //
        ->with($request->only('username', 'password'));
}

public function postLogin(Request $request)
{
    // Create the array using the values from the session
    $credentials = [
        'username' => session('username'),
        'password' => session('password'),
    ];

    // Attempt to login the user
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

    return 'Failure';
}
```

I strongly recommend you against using this approach. This way the implementation of `postLogin()` method which is supposed to be responsible to login users gets coupled with session data which is not good. This way, you're not able to use `postLogin` independently from the `postRegister`.

#### 2. Login the user right after the registration

This is a slightly better solution; If you decided that you need to log in the user right after the registration, why not just doing that?

Note that Laravel's own authentication controller [does it automatically](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/532d1148a92c9b78d5248d0ab9459afc30a048c8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php#L35).

By the way, here's what I mean:
*(Ideally this should be broken down into multiple methods, just like Laravel's own authentication controller. But it's just an example to get you started.)*

```php
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $input = $request->all();

    $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);

    User::create($input);

    // event(UserWasCreated::class);

    if (Auth::attempt($request->only('username', 'password'))) {
        return redirect()
            ->route('dashboard')
            ->with('Welcome! Your account has been successfully created!');
    }

    // Redirect
    return redirect()
        // To the previous page (probably the one generated by a `getRegister` method)
        ->back()
        // And with the input data (so that the form will get populated again)
        ->withInput();
}
```

But still, it's **far from perfect**! There are many other ways to tackle this. One could be using [events](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/events), throwing [exceptions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors) on failure and [redirecting using custom exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18103197/65732). But I'm not gonna explore them as there's already [a solution perfectly designed for this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication).

If you want to write your own authentication controller, that's fine. You'll learn a lot along the way. But I strongly suggest reading Laravel's own authentication code, especially [`RegistersUsers`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/532d1148a92c9b78d5248d0ab9459afc30a048c8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/RegistersUsers.php) and [`AuthenticatesUsers`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/532d1148a92c9b78d5248d0ab9459afc30a048c8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) traits in order to learn from it.

And one more note; you don't need that `Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable` trait in your `User` model as it's already extending [`Authenticatable`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/532d1148a92c9b78d5248d0ab9459afc30a048c8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php) which use that trait.

Comment: Many many thanks for everything, although solution 1 doesn't really turn out that well, and I'm facing quite a number of errors for solution 2... :(

Comment: You're welcome. What type of errors are you encountering?

Comment: I still get a 'failure' for solution 1 (flashing), and when I did "dd" credentials was working for postRegister() but becomes null when I do it in postLogin()

Comment: That is awesome! :)

Comment: You were right; there was an issue with the first solution's code, I fixed it and explained the issue with code comments. Please test it again. The second one was working just fine. Regarding that `dd` thing, that's expected behavior; there's no request data in `postLogin`, so it's all `null`. I explained why in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131806/discussion-between-programming-duders-and-sepehr).

Comment: what about if i use different mysql table name or model for login

Answer (score 4):

You should hash your password everytime you insert a row bcrypt(pass). Auth::attempt assumes that the password being retrieved from the database is hashed

Answer (score -2):

`Auth::attempt` uses `\Hash::make($someString)` to generate the hash. You should use this as well in order to generate same hashes from same strings (I assume the seed is different than with `bcrypt()` function).

So change this line:

```
$password = bcrypt($request['password']);
```

To:

```
$password = \Hash::make($request['password']);
```

Comment: This was awesome, but it still didn't solve my problem, sadly... :(

Comment: Hmm, did you try creating new user after changing the code? And are you sure the users are getting saved to the database?

Comment: Yes, I had. Users are saved in the database, I'll post an update in the question above... :)

Comment: Both are the same. The [`bcrypt` function](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/66976ba3f559ee6ede4cc865ea995996cd42ee1b/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L192) is just a helper for the same functionality.

Comment: Oh okay. Then I have no idea what it could be.