# Laravel Auth Attempt not working with Custom User Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I generated a different table to store users for my website. Name of the table is tblusers. I am registering new users with a controller method register(), in which i added this code

```
public function register(){
    return User::create([
        'User_Email' => 'test@example.com',
        'User_UserName' => 'test@example.com',
        'User_Password' => bcrypt('123'),
        'User_Address' => 'ABCD....',
        'User_IsActive' => 1,
        'User_FullName' => 'Burhan Ahmed',
        'User_AppID' => 1,
        'User_IsVerified' => 1
    ]);
}
```

It adds above dummy data successfully in Database. Then i tried to login with above given credentials using below code:

```
dd(Auth::attempt(['User_UserName' => 'test@example.com', 'User_Password' => '123']));
```

But above statement always returns false, Why? Am i missing something. I tried to pass actual bcrypt code instead '123' in above array it returns the same result always. Below is my Model Class

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

//class User extends Authenticatable
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;
    protected $table = 'tblusers';
    protected $primaryKey = 'User_ID';
    public $timestamps = false;
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'User_UserName', 'User_Email', 'User_Password', 'User_Address', 'User_FullName', 'User_IsActive', 'User_IsVerified'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'User_Password'
    ];
}
```

I am using Laravel 5.4, i followed all the authentication steps but not matter what i pass it always return false.

Comment: Laravel does not know that your `User_Password` field has been encrypted in the database.

Comment: did you look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41342907/laravel-authattempt-returns-false

Comment: So i have to change model name like SiteUsers etc & update auth file? Then it will work?

Comment: Is there no way to tell users guard to use a specific model to authenticate?

Comment: If You Havent' Changed the default Path of the model  You can pass table name inside your model  with `$table` property

Comment: I already did that protected $table = 'tblusers'; Kindly check above given model code

Answer (score 1):

if You want to Change the default table of login folow the steps

For Example You are Changing it to `login_table`

Step1:

change the table property in `User.php` **(User Model)**

```
/**
 * The table associated with the model.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $table = 'login_table';
```

Step1:

**IF YOU ARE BEGGINER**

Now You need to change the table name `users`  to `login_table`

**IF PROJECT IS TEAM COLLBRATION MAKE THE MIGRATION WITH `login_table`**

> php artisan make:migration create_login_table_table

and add the columns available in the `users` table

Step3:

Now open the file `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.php`

You will find method `validator` as

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }
```

Now You need to change `unique:users` to `unique:login_table`

```
protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:login_table',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }
```

Hope it helps and it works fine for me **@ Md.Sukel Ali**

Comment if it not works